# AS3 need open a new socket in every Message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, actionscript-3, flash

I made a conection between a nodeJS server and Flash socket client.

When I  open the client, the conection with the server is successfull, but I can send only one message on this socket conection. if I want send more messages i need to open another conection for every message. if I don't open this new conection, the socket dont send more data.

note: I work in flashdevelop

Question:

This is the normal way to send data from the client socket to the server? if its not the way, can you show me how send more messages with only one conection socket?

my server code:

```js
try {
    Security.allowDomain('xxx.xxx.x.xx');
    Security.loadPolicyFile("xmlsocket://xxx.xxx.x.xx:3000");
} catch (e) {

}

var net = require('net');


var server = net.createServer(function(stream) {
    stream.addListener("connect", function() {
        console.log("Client connected");
        stream.write("hello\r\n");
    });

    stream.addListener("data", function(data) {
        console.log(stream);
        console.log("Received from client: " + data);
        stream.write(data);
    });

    stream.addListener("end", function() {
        console.log("Client disconnected");
        stream.end();
    });
});

server.listen(3000, "xxx.xxx.x.xx");
console.log("running");
```

my AS3 client code:

```js
package ejempo1
{    import flash.display.MovieClip;
     import flash.events.Event;
     import flash.events.MouseEvent;
     import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
     import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
     import flash.text.*;
     import flash.utils.*;

     import flash.display.Sprite;
     import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
     import flash.net.Socket;

     public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        private var socket:Socket;

        public function Main()
        {

            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);


            //socket de conexion
            socket = new Socket();
            
            socket.connect("xxx.xxx.x.xx", 3000);
            socket.writeUTFBytes("Hello server");//this message work fine

            socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, connectHandler);
            socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, socketDataHandler);

        }
        
        private function connectHandler(e:Event):void {
            trace(e);
            trace("connect");
        }
        
        private var toRead:int = 0;
        
        private function socketDataHandler(e:ProgressEvent):void {
            trace("socketDataHandler: " + e);
            var str:String = socket.readUTFBytes(e.bytesLoaded);
            trace("server say:"+str);
            
        }


        public function send(data:Object):void {
            socket.writeObject(data);
            socket.flush();
        }
        
        
        private function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
                socket.connect("xxx.xxx.x.xx", 3000);//if I delete this line, the next code line dont work when I make a click.
                socket.writeUTFBytes("pepe");
             
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the way it works. You connect to server send request then receive response and connection closes. If you need persistent connection you should look at websockets.

Comment: Tra to listen to these events as well, maybe you could get a hint from their error messages: socket.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, closeHandler); 
socket.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);  socket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);

Comment: Just to clarify @Molda, you speak about the server side I guess. The `Socket` class on the client side allows persistent connections. Looks like this is a possible source for confusion/wrong expectations about behaviour.

Comment: Thanks so much !! ^^